# How can i add data to a chart in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, plotly

I have a Flask script on my backend. Every tot seconds I'm sending through `SocketIO` an array of numbers, it's always the same array but with new values added. How can I take that array and use it to plot my numbers on a chart?

```
socket.on('two', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.num)
});

Plotly.plot('chart',[{
    y: ts,
    type:'line'
}]);

var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[ts[0]]]}, [0]);
    cnt++;
    if(cnt > 500) {
        Plotly.relayout('chart',{
            xaxis: {
                range: [cnt-500,cnt]
            }
        });
    }
},15);
```

I tried to put my chart inside `socket.on` but it won't work. Instead of creating a line. In fact, it will only create random traces without plotting anything. Any advice is appreciated!